# Cumulative average in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I'm working with csv files.

I'd like a to create a continuously updated average of a sequence. ex;

I'd like to output the average of each individual value of a list

```
list; [a, b, c, d, e, f]
formula:

(a)/1= ?

(a+b)/2=?

(a+b+c)/3=?

(a+b+c+d)/4=?

(a+b+c+d+e)/5=?

(a+b+c+d+e+f)/6=?
```

To demonstrate:

if i have a list; `[1, 4, 7, 4, 19]`

my output should be; `[1, 2.5, 4, 4, 7]`

explained;

```
(1)/1=1

(1+4)/2=2.5

(1+4+7)/3=4

(1+4+7+4)/4=4

(1+4+7+4+19)/5=7
```

As far as my python file it is a simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('somecsvfile.csv')

x = [] #has to be a list of 1 to however many rows are in the "numbers" column, will be a simple [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] etc...

#x will be used to divide the numbers selected in y to give us z

y = df[numbers]

z = #new dataframe derived from the continuous average of y

plt.plot(x, z)

plt.show()
```

If numpy is needed that is no problem.

Comment: What does your CSV file look like?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "cumulative average/mean".

Answer (score 3):

[`pandas.DataFrame.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) is what you need.

Using it you can just call `df.expanding().mean()` to get the result you want:

```
mean = df.expanding().mean()

print(mean)

Out[10]: 
0   1.0
1   2.5
2   4.0
3   4.0
4   7.0
```

If you want to do it just in one column, use [`pandas.Series.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html).

Just use the column instead of `df`:

```
df['column_name'].expanding().mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` to get cumulative sum and then divide to get the running average.

```
x = np.array([1, 4, 7, 4, 19])
np.cumsum(x)/range(1,len(x)+1)
print (z)
```

output:

```
[1.  2.5 4.  4.  7. ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a complete answer to your question, filling in the blanks of your code using `numpy` and plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#df = pd.read_csv('somecsvfile.csv')
#instead I just create a df with a column named 'numbers'
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 4, 7, 4, 19], columns = ['numbers',])

x = range(1, len(df)+1)  #x will be used to divide the numbers selected in y to give us z

y = df['numbers']
z = np.cumsum(y) / np.array(x)

plt.plot(x, z, 'o')
plt.xticks(x)
plt.xlabel('Entry')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative average')
```

[image: cumulative-average-plot]

But as pointed out by Augusto, you can also just put the whole thing into a `DataFrame`. Adding a bit more to his approach:

```
n = [1, 4, 7, 4, 19]
df = pd.DataFrame(n, columns = ['numbers',])
#augment the index so it starts at 1 like you want
df.index = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)

# create a new column for the cumulative average
df = df.assign(cum_avg = df['numbers'].expanding().mean())
#    numbers  cum_avg
# 1        1      1.0
# 2        4      2.5
# 3        7      4.0
# 4        4      4.0
# 5       19      7.0

# plot
df['cum_avg'].plot(linestyle = 'none',
                   marker = 'o',
                   xticks = df.index,
                   xlabel = 'Entry',
                   ylabel = 'Cumulative average')
```